# Compare string and join value into one field in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm writing a script to modify csv file

Here's my csv file:

> "ID", "Subject" , "Channels", "Description" 
>   "24" , "Bind-0.9.3" , "Linux", "BIND (Berkeley Internet Name Domain) is an implementation of the DNS (Domain Name System) protocols" 
>   "24" , "Bind-0.9.3", "Fedora", "BIND (Berkeley Internet Name Domain) is an implementation of the DNS (Domain Name System) protocols" 
>   "25" , "Tar-8.0.1" , "Debian", "Tar Package" 
>   "25" , "Tar-8.0.1", "Ubuntu" , "Tar Package"

Now, I want to compare "ID" value . If they are same value, could we join "Channels" into one field

Here's expected result:

> "ID", "Subject" , "Channels", "Description" 
>   "24" , "Bind-0.9.3" , "Linux , Fedora", "BIND (Berkeley Internet Name Domain) is an implementation of the DNS (Domain Name System) protocols" 
>   "25" , "Tar-8.0.1" , "Debian , Ubuntu", "Tar Package"

Does anyone have an idea using awk, sed or something else in my case ?  
Thanks so much 
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"; OFS=" , " }
NR==1 { print; next }
{
    subj[$1] = $2
    desc[$1] = $4
    if ($1 in chans) {
        chans[$1] = chans[$1] OFS $3
    }
    else {
        chans[$1] = $3
        cnt2chan[++numChans] = $1
    }
}
END {
    for (chanNr=1; chanNr<=numChans; chanNr++) {
        chan = cnt2chan[chanNr]
        gsub(/\"/,"",chans[chan])
        print chan, subj[chan], "\"" chans[chan] "\"", desc[chan]
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
"ID", "Subject" , "Channels", "Description"
"24" , "Bind-0.9.3" , "Linux , Fedora" , "BIND (Berkeley Internet Name Domain) is an implementation of the DNS (Domain Name System) protocols"
"25" , "Tar-8.0.1" , "Debian , Ubuntu" , "Tar Package"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^("[0-9]*")\s*,\s*"[^"]*"\s*,\s*"([^"]*)".*\n(\1\s*,\s*"[^"]*"\s*,\s*")/\3\2,/;ta;P;D' file
```

Keep a running window of 2 lines in the pattern space and if the beginning of the those lines are the same combine the channels into the second line, remove the first line and repeat.

N.B. the headers will be untouched as they do not fullfill the required pattern.